# How to create a ThreadPoolExecutor that creates threads as needed and expires them when applicable?

Tags: java, executorservice, threadpoolexecutor

My use-case:

- Set a minimum size 'N' for the thread pool which implies that 'N' threads are always available after the Executor startup.
- Set a maximum size 'M' for thread pool.
- Incoming tasks should get queued when all 'M' threads are busy.
- Expire (M -N) threads based on a timeout on idle-state.

I believe a similar setup is possible for pool manager behind the HttpClient. I'm trying to achieve it using ThreadPoolExecutor but unable to find a way. Is it possible?

Here's an example to test.

```
public class ExecutorExample {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        int minPoolSize = 2;
        int maxPoolSize = 10;
        int ttlMillis = 100;
        ThreadPoolExecutor startupExecutor = new ThreadPoolExecutor(minPoolSize, 
                maxPoolSize, // surprisingly this is not obeyed.
                ttlMillis, 
                TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS, 
                new LinkedBlockingQueue<Runnable>());

        for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
            System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName() + ":" + startupExecutor.getCorePoolSize());
            startupExecutor.execute(new MyRunnable(i));
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
            Thread.sleep(1000);
            System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName() + ":" + startupExecutor.getCorePoolSize());
        }
    }

}

class MyRunnable implements Runnable {

    int n;

    public MyRunnable(int n) {
        this.n = n;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {
            Thread.sleep(2000);
            System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName() + ":" + n);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: Doesn't `ThreadPoolExecutor(corePoolSize, maximumPoolSize, keepAliveTime, unit, workQueue)` suit your needs?

Comment: @RomanPuchkovskiy which queue object do you have in mind? I will test.

Comment: Yours is such a strange requirement... Why do you need to increase the number of threads from N to M *before* incoming tasks are queued?

Answer (score 1):

How about this:

```
        ThreadPoolExecutor executor = new ThreadPoolExecutor(corePoolSize, maximumPoolSize, keepAliveTime, unit, workQueue);
```

[ThreadPoolExecutor](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ThreadPoolExecutor.html)

EDIT:  Typically the queue I use is a bounded blocking queue.

```
BlockingQueue<Runnable> workQueue = new ArrayBlockingQueue(queueCapacity, true);
```

EDIT2:  The max pool size only kicks in when the queue is full.  Since you are using an unbounded queue, then the number of threads will not go above 2.  Se link below.

[rules-of-a-threadpoolexecutor-pool-size](http://www.bigsoft.co.uk/blog/index.php/2009/11/27/rules-of-a-threadpoolexecutor-pool-size)

Put size 1 and you’ll see the difference.

```
new LinkedBlockingQueue<>(1));
```

EDIT 3:  In your example change `startupExecutor.getCorePoolSize()` with `startupExecutor.getPoolSize()`.

Comment: I don't this is expiring the threads after the timeout. Could you update it with the real implementation of the Queue you'd want me to use?

Comment: Do you mean expire the threads after they have been executed?

Comment: Expire idle threads after a timeout (and obviously queue is empty because the thread is idle). I posted some sample code for you to test your ThreadPoolExecutor.

Comment: Just ran your example, interesting to see that the maxPoolSize was not followed.  Playing around with it.